# Changing the description of an id object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am storing items in an array to be stored in myTableView like so:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [nameField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.objects insertObject:@"New Friend" atIndex:0];

    //[self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Once The object is created, it is stored into the table View as "New Friend".  What method can I use to change "New Friend" to something else after the object is created?

Something like the following would be ideal if there is a similar method:

```
[self.detailItem changeDescription:string1]
```

Comment: You would have to delete the "New Friend" entry in the dictionary and re-insert the object under a different key.  ("New Friend" is not a "description" -- it's a "key" in the dictionary.)

Comment: So how could you set the key and access the description?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218256/change-a-value-within-a-nsmutablearray

Comment: "description" is a method that every Objective-C object supports -- the method that prints out it's identity when you use NSLog on it.  And a "key" does not belong to the object in a dictionary -- it belongs to the dictionary.  You have some serious misconceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a deep misconception about what your code is doing. "The object" is not some object of unspecified type whose *description* is "New Friend". You have actually inserted the `NSString` instance whose value is "New Friend" into the array at index 0.

You can't change the value of an `NSString` instance. It's immutable. You could replace the object at index 0 with a different string object, but I think that's still not what you mean.

You presumably want your table view to represent some sort of more meaningful objects, like perhaps `Person` objects. If so, then you need to declare and define such a `Person` class, perhaps with properties like `name`, `age`, etc. Then, you would create an instance of this `Person` class and store that in your array (which would be shown in the table view). Later, if desired, you could change the value of such an instance's `name` property.